# Joint and Conditional pdf of Two Normal r.v.'s

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Given two uncorrelated Gaussian random variables,

X ~ $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$

Y ~ $N(0,1)$

Find $f_{y|x}(y|x)$, $f_{x,y}(x,y)$

If I can find either the conditional probability or the joint probability, I can solve for the other using the relation: $f_{y|x}(y|x) = \frac{f_{x,y}(x,y)}  {f_{x}(x)}$.

I know if X and Y are independent, then their jonit pdf will be: $f_{x,y}(x,y) = f_{x}(x)f_{y}(y)$. However, I do not know if X and Y are independent, only that they are uncorrelated. If X and Y are $\mathbf{jointly}$ normal, then they are independent (since they are uncorrelated), but this leads me back to being able to solve for their joint pdf, which I am not sure how to obtain.

Could anyone point me to the right direction of where to start? I see a few previous questions regarding this topic, but it seems they started with the assumption that X and Y were independent, which I don't believe I can make in this case.

Comment: Thanks for that link (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent ). That's interesting... I haven't come across such examples before. I guess this means you are stuck unless you know more about the sample space and what $X$ and $Y$ refer to (such as a "real world" meaning). The examples in the link, while perfectly valid, are kind of contrived with $Y$ somehow deriving from $X$.